# C# - Stream/FileStream EOF

Tags: c#, stream, eof

Is anyone familiar with a way to find out you're at the end of the file?
I'm using BinaryReader and tried PeekChar - but it throws an exception.  Any other suggestions?

Thanks.

Comment: Do you want this to work for files only (which are seekable, I think), or for streams in general?

Comment: What exception does it throw?

Comment: The output char buffer is too small to contain the decoded characters, encoding 'Unicode (UTF-8)' fallback 'System.Text.DecoderReplacementFallback'.
Parameter name: chars

Answer (score 11):

From a `Stream`, if you `Read(buffer, offset, count)` you'll get a non-positive result, and if you `Peek()` you'll get a negative result.

With a `BinaryReader`, [the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.binaryreader.peekchar.aspx) suggests that `PeekChar()` should return negative:

> #### Return Value
>
> Type: System.Int32
>   The next available character, or -1 if no more characters are available or the stream does not support seeking.

are you sure this isn't a *corrupt* stream? i.e. the remaining data cannot form a complete `char` from the given encoding?

Comment: I've done while (binReader.PeekChar() ! = -1 ) {...}
This is what I get:
The output char buffer is too small to contain the decoded characters, encoding 'Unicode (UTF-8)' fallback 'System.Text.DecoderReplacementFallback'.
Parameter name: chars

Comment: @MarcGravell There is probably a bug/feature somewhere in the `DecoderReplacementFallback` so that `new BinaryReader(new MemoryStream(new byte[] { 194, 0, 0 })).PeekChar()` will throw an exception (not all the illegal sequences of three bytes will throw... For example `{ 192, 0, 0 }` won't

Answer (score 2):

If your stream supports seeking (check this using the BaseStream.CanSeek property), check the Position property of the BaseStream, like so:

```
if (myBinaryReader.BaseStream.CanSeek){
   bool atEnd = (myBinaryReader.BaseStream.Position == myBinaryReader.BaseStream.Length - 1)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Checking whether the position of the reader is less than its length does the trick

```
While BinReader.Position < BinReader.Length
{
 ... BinReader.Read() ...
}
```

Comment: Using `Stream.Position` or `Stream.Length` will cause an exception if `CanSeek == false`.

Answer (score 0):

I'll add my suggestion: if you don't need the "encoding" part of the `BinaryReader` (so you don't use the various `ReadChar`/`ReadChars`/`ReadString`) then you can use an encoder that won't ever throw and that is always one-byte-per-char. `Encoding.GetEncoding("iso-8859-1")` is perfect for this. The `iso-8859-1` encoding is a one-byte-per-character encoding that maps 1:1 all the first 256 characters of Unicode (so the `byte` 254 is the `char` 254 for example)