# Is there a reason not to check for EOF in a C# stream with Position and Length?

Tags: c#, filestream, eof

In looking for a good way to read until the end of a FileStream I came across an older post, [C# - Stream/FileStream EOF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5016403/c-sharp-stream-filestream-eof), in which three answers are provided (though none accepted). When working with them though, I also recalled that FileStream objects have the properties Position and Length. It seems to me that (for an appropriately opened `FileStream fs`)

```
while (fs.Position < fs.Length)
{
    // Read more from file
}
```

should be a straightforward way to read until the end of the file. This method and those properties aren't mentioned though, and I'm just curious:

Are there are any disadvantages to this, that other properties or methods might avoid?

Answer (score 1):

The one disadvantage is that not all `Stream` instances have a length.  It is possible for a `Stream` to be backing a network connection which has no definitive length.  Hence the `Length` property will just throw an exception.